# Javafx text fields values worked only for the first user attempt

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

Summary:
I am designing a JavaFX program that tests a matrix if it is a magic square or not. I have two buttons (submit and reset) with 2 handlers for each one. When the user entered the values and submitted them for the first time the program worked fine. However, in the second attempt, the program's results are always (" it is not a magic square").

Here is the code

```
package com.example.team9project;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MagicSquare extends Application {
    // text entries for the matrix
     TextField [][] fields = new TextField[3][3];


     // the appropriate pane for a matrix
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    // helpfull variable for isMagicSquare method
    final int correctSum=15;
    int sumRow=0, sumColumn=0, sumMdg=0, sumSdg=0;


    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        // creating buttons
        Button submit = new Button("Submit");
        Button reset = new Button("Reset");
        // designing the pane
        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
        // adding elements to the pane
        gridPane.add(submit,1,3,2,1);
        gridPane.add(reset,2,3,2,1);
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            for (int j=0;j<3; j++){
                fields[i][j]= new TextField();
                gridPane.add( fields[i][j],i,j);
            }
        }
        // add the choices to the combo box
        //for(int i=1; i<=9; i++){
            //choices.getItems().add(i);
       // }
        // display combo box for
        //choices.setOnAction(e ->
                //setCell(choices.getValue())
        //);

        reset.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                              @Override
                              public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                                  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                                      for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
                                          fields[i][j].setText("");
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                          }
        );


        //submit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            //@Override
            //public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

            //}
       // });
        SubmitHandler handler1= new SubmitHandler();
        submit.setOnAction(handler1);







        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 450, 100);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Magic Square");
        primaryStage.show();

    }
    //public void setCell(Integer element){

        //choices.getItems().remove(element);

    //}

    // return true if the array represents a square matrix and false otherwise
    public  boolean isMagicSquare(int[][] myArray){

        for( int i = 0 ; i < myArray.length  ; i ++) {

            sumRow = sumColumn = 0;

            sumMdg = sumMdg + myArray[i][i];

            sumSdg = sumSdg + myArray[i][myArray.length - 1 - i];



            for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length ; j++) {

                sumRow = sumRow + myArray[i][j];

                sumColumn = sumColumn + myArray[j][i];

            }



            if (sumColumn != correctSum || sumRow != correctSum)

                return false;

        }



        return (sumMdg == correctSum ) && ( sumSdg == correctSum );

    }


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch();
}

class SubmitHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event){
            int[][] values= new int[3][3];
            for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
                    // check if  the fields are empty
                    if(fields[i][j].getText().compareTo("")==0){
                        fields[i][j].setText("0");
                    }
                    // convert the text fields values' to integers
                    values[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(fields[i][j].getText());
                }
            }
            if(isMagicSquare(values)){
                System.out.println("The matrix is magic square");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("The matrix is not a magic square");
            }
        }


}}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are not resetting the sumMdg & sumSdg variables. You need to reset these on the call of isMagicSquare().

```
public boolean isMagicSquare(int[][] myArray) {
    sumMdg= 0;
    sumSdg = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
       ...
       ...
       ...
    }
    return (sumMdg == correctSum) && (sumSdg == correctSum);
}
```